# Question about criteria of connectedness

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-writing, connectedness

I have to prove the following :

A) No proper non empty subset of $X$ is both open and closed in $X$ $implies$ that $X$ is not the union of two disjoint open subsets of itself.

Attempt at the proof:

I assumed that, No proper non empty subset of $X$ is both open and closed in $X$.Suppose on the contrary that $X$ = $U union U^c$ where both $U$ and $U^c$ are open.

Then their complements $U^c$ and $U$ respectively, are closed.

Hence $U$ and $U^c$ are both open and closed, a contradiction.

B) $X$ is not the union of two disjoint open subsets of itself $implies$ that $X$ is not the union of two disjoint closed subsets of itself.

Attempt at the proof:

Assume the first criterion holds true.

And suppose that $X$ is the disjoint union of two closed subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X$.

Then $A^c$ = $B$ and $B^c$ = $A$ and so both $A$ and $B$ should be open, and $X$ is their union, a contradiction.

Am i correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** For (A) and (B), try proving the contrapositive of the statements.

Comment: I have edited my post and tried to prove them using contradiction, could you, please take a look at it?

Comment: @johny: They look okay. As an aside, you have essentially proven the contrapositive, then claim a contradiction. If you think about it a little bit, you can streamline your proof just a little, and it may make it more intuitive for you. In the end, your proofs look fine, though.

Answer (score 1):

For any set subset $U \subset X$, you have that $U \cup U^c = X$, and that $U$ and $U^c$ are disjoint. So if both $U$ and $U^c$ are open, then...

Answer (score 1):

Your question can be, perhaps, more easily proved if you prove separatedly the following lemma, which is interesting in its own and helpful for other problems:

**Lemma:** Let $\;X\;$ be a topological space and let $\;\{0,1\}\;$ be the subspace of $\;\Bbb R\;$ with the inherited usual Euclidean topology (i.e., a discrete space with two points). Then $\;X\;$ is *disconnected* iff there exists a continuous surjection $\;X\to\{0,1\}\;$ .

Comment: Ah, now I understand and agree! +$1$